# Styling columns of the same class within the same row in Bootstrap 3 Grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3:

I have a row, div class="row", with 2 columns, both div class="col-xs-6". I want to style each column with different colors, say the background color, border, and padding of the column itself, but they are both of the same class "col-xs-6".

In rows, I can add a class name by changing div class="row" to div class="row top_row" to differentiate that specific row from all the other row classes. When I try to do the same with columns by changing div class="col-xs-6" to div class="col-xs-6 left_column", the style does not apply. Instead, all styling is removed for that specific column.

How do I apply different styles to columns of the same size (aka class name) within the same row?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2>I am a:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">woman</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">man</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2>interested in:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">women</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">men</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">both</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: you could use selector  +   or nth-child or nth-of-type or first-child, or last-child and so on , lot's of selector that you can find in jQuery too :)

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: "all styling is removed for that specific column" - sounds like you spelled the class names wrong...

Comment: i checked the spelling, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JoannaJogramma you got one example with nth-child below :) where nth-child(1) could have been :first-child and no need of adding :nth-child(2)to the class name, or :last-child instead of nth-child(2) and no need of  adding :nth-child(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nth-child() Selector

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2>I am a:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">woman</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">man</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2>interested in:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">women</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">men</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">both</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.col-xs-6:nth-child(1){
    background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

div.col-xs-6:nth-child(2){
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9BS36/

Comment: I realized it is unnecessary to refer to the child divs. I can label each column with a classname and header, like so: 
        <div class="col-xs-12 a_classname">
           <h1>header</h1>

and refer to the classname and header in the css, like so:

.a_classname {
     height: 100px;
     background-color: green;
}

h1 {
     position:absolute;
     top: 50%;
     text-align:center;
     line-height: 100px;
}

Thanks